# How can I repair damaged vinyl flooring over gypsum subfloor?

Tags: vinyl-flooring, drywall

While moving a new washer and dryer through our bathroom and into the attach laundry room, the moving guys made several silver-dollar sized chunks of damage to the bathroom floor.  The damage is pretty clean, but I was surprised to find what looks like drywall under it and clinging to the bottom of the flap of vinyl.

How can I repair this?  Is there a particular glue I should be using?

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the moving guys be fixing this?  If you are renting, you could get charged for the damage, even if repair is attempted.

Answer (score 2):

The white looking stuff is not gypsum, it is the backer that the finish facing is bonded to. If you look closely at it you will see it has the consistency of soft cardboard, it will flake a little and be slightly fibrous.

If you feel you should repair it, make sure the glue is flexible, since the flooring has a little give to it.

I would think if the movers damaged it, they would be responsible to fix it. They should have insurance to cover these items, since they are in the type of business where this type of stuff happens. They also, since that would be the case, have leads on companies that specialize in this type of repair. Take pictures of all the damage and send it to the company that did the moving, they have a reputation they want to keep in good standing, I would hope.

Answer (score 1):

The subfloor is not likely to be gypsum (drywall), but probably a floor leveling compound. If you reside in an apartment building it might also be the cementatious  (concrete-like) sub-floor that was poured over steel panels when the building was erected. More likely the leveling compound though. To repair the divot: vacuum out any loose debris. If the gouge is lower than the surrounding floor you can either: mix a small batch of compound and float it level or apply a dab of construction adhesive into the depression. If you decide to use the adhesive it would help to soften the loose piece of vinyl by gently heating it with a heat gun or hair dryer (only enough to make it pliable, it should only take 4-5 seconds). Once it is warmed hinge the piece back into position and with a strip of wood (pencil, tongue depressor, etc.) press it into the adhesive. Clean any adhesive squeeze out with mineral spirits and a rag before it dries . Cover the repair with painters tape for 24 hours.

Comment: Is cemenatious sub floor usually powdery and loose like drywall or is it harder like cement?  This stuff can be scraped out and is white and sandstone-like.

Comment: It can be powdery if it's been pulverized, but when cured to full strength it hardens to a solid rigid floor layer. It is a light weight cement-like material used in construction as a sub-floor. It is more porous than regular concrete. It is used primarily in apartment buildings that are multi-storied. The one downside is ( just as you experienced) that it is easily damaged by blunt force and sharp narrow objects.

Comment: That floor layer used in apartments is "gypcrete", which actually does contain gypsum as a filler and sound deadener.